# Load a site based on header request in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have different static sites hosted at `http://static.example.com/` and
I want to load different versions of the site based on the `X-Site-version` header sent to Nginx server. If no header is present than a default version should be loaded.

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
if header X-Site-version === 2
 load /www/static/v2

if header X-Siter-version === 1
 load /www/static/v1

else
 load /www/static/v0
```

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [root](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) directive to set the content resolution directory and with the [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive to set a default directory when your header is missing. A configuration like this should work:

```
map $http_x_site_version $site_directory {
    default    $http_x_site_version;
    ''         v0;
}

server {
        location / {
            root /www/static/$site_directory;
        }
}
```